# How do I change array values with dict keys?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have an 3d array that looks like this
With the shape (20001, 128, 128)

```
array([[[48, 48, 48, ..., 48, 48, 48],
        [48, 48, 48, ..., 48, 48, 48],
        [48, 48, 48, ..., 48, 48, 48],
        ...,
       [[12, 12, 12, ..., 12, 12, 12],
        [12, 12, 12, ..., 12, 12, 12],
        [12, 12, 12, ..., 12, 12, 12],
        ...,
        [19, 19, 19, ..., 12, 12, 12],
        [19, 19, 19, ..., 19, 12, 12],
        [19, 19, 19, ..., 19, 19, 19]],
```

And I have a dict that look like this

```
{1: [1, 39],
 2: [2, 5, 9, 20, 32, 42, 47, 72, 88, 91, 95],
 3: [3, 49, 55],
 4: [4, 24, 34, 40, 53, 76, 81, 90, 96],
 5: [6, 17, 30, 48, 83],
 6: [7, 13, 15, 16, 27, 44, 51, 54, 56, 75],
 7: [8, 50],
 8: [10, 19, 22, 35, 61, 63, 65],
 9: [11, 12, 21, 46, 52, 69, 78, 84, 89],
 10: [14, 36, 74],
 11: [18],
 12: [23, 38, 66, 97],
 13: [25],
 14: [26, 28, 29, 62, 64, 86, 94],
 15: [31, 59, 85],
 16: [33, 80],
 17: [37, 45, 60],
 18: [41, 92, 93],
 19: [43, 77, 79, 82],
 20: [57, 67],
 21: [58],
 22: [68],
 23: [70],
 24: [71],
 25: [73, 87],
 0: [0]}
```

So what im after is that if the array value = dict value to change the array value to the key, like this ->

```
array([[[5, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 5],
        ...,
        [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9]],
        ...,
        [8, 8, 8, ..., 9, 9, 9],
        [8, 8, 8, ..., 8, 9, 9],
        [8, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 8]],
```

Because 48 is in key 5,
12 is in key 9 etc

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reverse your original dictionary:

```
lookup_dict = {1: [1, 39],
 2: [2, 5, 9, 20, 32, 42, 47, 72, 88, 91, 95],
 3: [3, 49, 55],
 4: [4, 24, 34, 40, 53, 76, 81, 90, 96],
 5: [6, 17, 30, 48, 83],
 6: [7, 13, 15, 16, 27, 44, 51, 54, 56, 75],
 7: [8, 50],
 8: [10, 19, 22, 35, 61, 63, 65],
 9: [11, 12, 21, 46, 52, 69, 78, 84, 89],
 10: [14, 36, 74],
 11: [18],
 12: [23, 38, 66, 97],
 13: [25],
 14: [26, 28, 29, 62, 64, 86, 94],
 15: [31, 59, 85],
 16: [33, 80],
 17: [37, 45, 60],
 18: [41, 92, 93],
 19: [43, 77, 79, 82],
 20: [57, 67],
 21: [58],
 22: [68],
 23: [70],
 24: [71],
 25: [73, 87],
 0: [0]}

reversed_dict = {val: key for key, lst in lookup_dict.items() for val in lst}
```

Now, you could either iterate through the input array and set each item in a new array after looking it up from `reversed_dict`, and that would already be more efficient than [JRiggles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277551/843953) because you don't need to iterate through all the lists to find the new value.

However, if you put the values of this `reversed_dict` into an array, such that the key in the dict is the index in the array, then you can simply use numpy's inbuilt broadcasting ability to index into the array and get you the result of the correct shape. I prefer this approach because it's much faster:

```
max_index = max(reversed_dict.keys())

lookup_array = np.zeros((max_index+1,))
for k, v in reversed_dict.items():
    lookup_array[k] = v
```

And finally:

```
input_array = np.array([[[48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48],
        [48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48],
        [48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48]],
        
        [[12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12],
        [12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12],
        [12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12]],
        
        [[19, 19, 19,  12, 12, 12],
        [19, 19, 19,  19, 12, 12],
        [19, 19, 19,  19, 19, 19]]])

output_array = lookup_array[input_array]
```

Which gives:

```
array([[[5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.]],

       [[9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.],
        [9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.],
        [9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9.]],

       [[8., 8., 8., 9., 9., 9.],
        [8., 8., 8., 8., 9., 9.],
        [8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.]]])
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works as-is for `input_array` of *any* shape, and it's *super fast!*.

Timing the three approaches:

1. [JRiggles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277551/843953), `func1`
2. Looking up values from the reversed dictionary, `func2`
3. Indexing into the new numpy array, `func3`

```
import timeit

input_array = np.random.randint(0, max_index, (100, 100, 100))

def get_key(search_value):
    for key, num_list in lookup_dict.items():
         if search_value in num_list:
             return key

def func1(arr):
  arr = np.copy(arr)
  for outer_lst in arr:
    for sub_list in outer_lst:
        for index, value in enumerate(sub_list):
            new_val = get_key(value)  # get the key from 'dict'
            sub_list[index] = new_val  # replace old subarray value
  return arr

def func2(arr):
    arr = np.copy(arr)
    for outer_lst in arr:
        for sub_list in outer_lst:
            for index, value in enumerate(sub_list):
                new_val = reversed_dict[value]
                sub_list[index] = new_val
    return arr

def func3(arr):
    return lookup_array[arr]

t1 = timeit.timeit("func1(input_array)", globals=globals(), number=2)
print("t1 =", t1)
t2 = timeit.timeit("func2(input_array)", globals=globals(), number=2)
print("t2 =", t2)
t3 = timeit.timeit("func3(input_array)", globals=globals(), number=2)
print("t3 =", t3)
```

On my computer, this gives:

```
t1 = 25.02508409996517
t2 = 1.2259434000588953
t3 = 0.01203500002156943
```

In other words,

- JRiggles's approach is 20x slower than reversing the dictionary and looking up values in the reversed dictionary
- JRiggles's approach is ***2000***x slower than creating the array and using numpy to index into the array.

And this is with a test array that contains ~300x *fewer* elements than your input array does. With your array, the time savings will be *significantly* larger.

Comment: Reversing the lookup dictionary is clever. I confess that I don't have any real experience with Numpy since my job makes downloading modules a nightmare (it's absolutely draconian, and I've had to learn to make do withe the standard library). @CoolBeans, this is an objectively a better answer and I'm not even mad. Nicely done, Pranav!

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [  # Example list of lists - arbitrary values
    [11, 11, 12, 13],
    [24, 24, 24, 35],
    [16, 27, 27, 8]
]

dictionary = {
    1: [1, 39],
    2: [2, 5, 9, 20, 32, 42, 47, 72, 88, 91, 95],
    3: [3, 49, 55],
    4: [4, 24, 34, 40, 53, 76, 81, 90, 96],
    5: [6, 17, 30, 48, 83],
    6: [7, 13, 15, 16, 27, 44, 51, 54, 56, 75],
    7: [8, 50],
    8: [10, 19, 22, 35, 61, 63, 65],
    9: [11, 12, 21, 46, 52, 69, 78, 84, 89],
    10: [14, 36, 74],
    11: [18],
    12: [23, 38, 66, 97],
    13: [25],
    14: [26, 28, 29, 62, 64, 86, 94],
    15: [31, 59, 85],
    16: [33, 80],
    17: [37, 45, 60],
    18: [41, 92, 93],
    19: [43, 77, 79, 82],
    20: [57, 67],
    21: [58],
    22: [68],
    23: [70],
    24: [71],
    25: [73, 87],
    0: [0]
}

def get_key(search_value):
    for key, num_list in dictionary.items():
         if search_value in num_list:
             return key

for sub_list in arr:
    for index, value in enumerate(sub_list):
        new_val = get_key(value)  # get the key from 'dict'
        sub_list[index] = new_val  # replace old subarray value

print(arr)  # QED - see new array below
# [
#     [9, 9, 9, 6],
#     [4, 4, 4, 8],
#     [6, 6, 6, 7]
# ]
```

Comment: Note that getting `new_val` and setting `sub_list[index] = new_val` isn't strictly necessary; you could simply use `sub_list[index] = get_key(value)`, but I wanted to illustrate step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks!! It works but having problem looping because my array is in 3d, do you have any suggestions to that?

Comment: You'll need an additional iterator (basically, a for loop for each array dimension). Ex.: `for arr in three_d: for sub_list in arr: for index, value in enumerate(sub_list):  # yadda yadda`. Essentially, each for loop is iterating over a single dimension of the array. If you can edit your question to include your 3D array, I'll try to edit my answer with a workable example.

Comment: I see, i have edited it now it that makes things clearer